# "If" and css property

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement, colors, conditional-statements

I want to do really simple thing.
I want to change the text color in 'blue' if a text has the color 'red'.
I tried this code, but it doesn't work.

```
$(function(){
if ($('h1').css('color') == 'red'){ 
    $('h1').css({'color': 'blue'});
} });
```

Thanks for your precious help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WvAaK/1/)

```
$(function(){
if ($('h1').css('color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'){ // check visibility
    $('h1').css('color','blue');
} });
```

you can also try

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Answer (score 0):

If you're not utilising jQuery for any more than this problem then here's a plain JS example to save a few kilobytes:

```
(function() {
    var headings = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");

    for (var i = 0, len = headings.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (headings[i].style.color === "red") {
            headings[i].style.color = "blue";
        }
    }
})();
```